# How to run test for Grails service

Tags: grails, grails-3.0, grails-services

When I run

```
grails test-app MessageServiceSpec
```

or 
    grails test-app mypackage.MessageServiceSpec

I always get an error

```
No tests found for given includes: [MessageServiceSpec]
```

What is wrong here?

UPDATE: run command is

```
grails test-app -unit packageName.MessageServiceSpec
```

Comment: What's inside of MessageServiceSpec?

Comment: No matter, test-app could not find the test file itself, because "-unit" parameter was not specified. Now it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

grails test-app -unit mypackage.MessageService